# Having trouble in creating new row/ cell with custom labels

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Using Swift, My custom cell has 4 labels which I would like to edit when adding the new row/cell to the tableview.

On top of my app in the bar I have an add button which is supposed to add the new cell/row to the table view but only the first one works and when I add a second cell/row it changes and becomes smaller.

I know the code is wrong obviously but I can't seem to fix it as its using an array called objects but I can't seem to be able to add multiple strings to the object to be used in the table view.

I'm using the standard Master Detail template for the project but in changing the code to be custom to my liking I ran into these problems.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    //let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! String // NSDate
    //cell.textLabel!.text = object.description

    cell.firstLabel.text = "name"
    cell.secondLabel.text = "bought"
    cell.thirdLabel.text = "18"
    cell.fourthLabel.text = "30"

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

@objc
func insertNewObject(_ sender: Any) {

    // Adding cell with new added info

    // can not be an array of strings, has to be an array of an array of strings, doesn't it?
    // "tester" is was there from the project template
    let test: String = "tester"
    objects.insert(test, at: 0) // NSDate()

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}

// MARK: - Segues

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}

@IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!
var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var objects = [Any]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Custom Cell
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self
    self.myTableView.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem

    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(insertNewObject(_:)))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    if let split = splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }
}
```

[image: pic1]

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your problem. Did you mean you have problems displaying all labels in your tableViewCell? Try increasing the height of your tableViewCell by adding this method to your view controller:

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       
        return 200
  }`

Comment: Yes thank you but also a second thing, i'm using an array called `objects` but nothing seems to be saving to the object, when I click the add button it adds a cell but `objects` is not being used. I would like to save the labels to to objects so it's easier to save or edit, and can easily be used with .count

Comment: That's because you never assign any other text to your tableViewCell labels than your strings ("name", "bought", "18", "30")

Lets assume your custom object contains four strings each (with property names "firstString", "secondString", "thirdString" and "fourthString" . One for each label.

Simply assign the corresponding strings like this:

`cell.firstLabel.text =  objects[indexPath.row].firstString`
`cell.secondLabel.text = objects[indexPath.row].secondString`

and so one.

Comment: In order to prevent creating a custom string object, you could also simply us e a multidimensional array, that means you put an array with four strings (one for each row) into your object-array:

`let objects = [["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"],["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"],["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"]]`

Comment: In case of using a multidimensional array, you would simply assign your string values like this:

`let currentSubarray = objects[indexPath.row]`

`cell.firstLabel.text = currentSubarray[0]`
`cell.firstLabel.text = currentSubarray[1]`
`cell.firstLabel.text = currentSubarray[2]`
`cell.firstLabel.text = currentSubarray[3]`

Hope iI could help, I appreciate if you upvote my comments, if you like my advice. :)

Comment: Yes thats what I need! How would I go about this exactly? I added `cell.firstLabel.text = objects[indexPath.row][0]` to `cellForRowAt` but how about, `func insertNewObject`. Also what is `currentSubarray`?

Comment: if you want to insert a new object, you basically just could append a new subarray to your objects array property and reload your tableView afterwards. Please note that you should define it as a "var" in order to make it mutable.

`self.objects.append(["X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"])`
`self.myTableView.reloadData()`

Comment: "currentSubarray" is just the custom name for the corresponding subarray-instance, you can name it how you like.

Comment: so I create `var objects = [[String]]()` and `var currentSubarray = [[String]]()` ?

Comment: No, you create your multidimensional objects array once and append further subarrays if you want to manipulate the data source of your table view (add more cells). You could basically also just access the corresponding subarray like this:

`self.firstLabel.text = objects[indexPath.row][0]`
`self.secondLabel.text = objects[indexPath.row][1]`
`self.thirdLabel.text = objects[indexPath.row][2]`
`self.fourthLabel.text = objects[indexPath.row][3]`

But code looks more redundant if you do it like this

Comment: so i replace `cell.firstLabel` with `self.firstLabel`? Sorry just a bit confused, any way you can add it as an answer so its more readable?

Comment: I posted an answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to our previous conversation try something like this:

```
@IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!

private var objects = [["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"],["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"],["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"],["D1", "D2", "D3", "D4"]]

private func insertNewObject() {

    self.objects.append(["NewString1", "NewString2", "NewString3", "NewString4"])
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.objects.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200 // add the height you like
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.firstLabel.text = objects[indexPath.row][0]
    cell.secondLabel.text = objects[indexPath.row][1]
    cell.thirdLabel.text = objects[indexPath.row][2]
    cell.fourthLabel.text = objects[indexPath.row][3]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try to implement method  tableView(_:heightForRowAt:) -> CGFloat

Please try to return 88.0f and see the difference